# Split doxygen commands

Tags: c, doxygen

I want to use doxygen in order to comment c-files. Therefore I want to start a doxygen command then there is a part of code and afterwards there should be the rest of the doxygen command.

Is there any way to tell doxygen that the command is not finished?

Example:
I want to draw a picture of a switch case and I want to add blocks for each case in the picture.

```
switch (condition)

{

  case VALUE_1:

    /**
    \dot
    digraph TESTMAIN {

    case_1 [label="Init"];

    ## here I want to stop the doxygen command ##
    */

  case VALUE_2:

    /**

    ## here I want to go on with the old command ##

    case_1 -> case_2 [label="Zustandsübergang1"];
    case_2 [shape=diamond, label="Aufbau"];
    }
    \enddot
    */

 }
```

Comment: What kind of command would that apply to?

Comment: can you write a practial example?

Comment: @user3483931 please edit your question and put there the code

Comment: I added the code in the main dialogue

Comment: By 'stop' I think you mean 'pause', so that the command can 'resume' in the next comment block.  And the reason is so that the comments stay with the related code.

Comment: What if instead of pause and resume, you close the command and re-open it again under the same name? would \dot digraph TESTMAIN {...} complain that your are reusing the name or does it add on to it?  (if it works, write it as an answer and I'll vote for you ;)

Comment: Yes I want to pause and resume ;-). The problem if I finish my command, doxygen/graphviz print each time a separate picutre, but I want one picture of the whole switch case statement. And I dont want to do it in one place, because I have very big switch cases and therefor I want to comment each case where it is coded.